# use content type field value as css class in views

Tags: views

I have a content type article with a field called 'type'. Based on the value of this field I want to display my content type differently in a view that I created with the Views module. In order to do that I would like to add the value of the type field as a css class to each item in that view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way to achieve this was actually use the views module itself. The value of the type field can be easily used as a row class. Thanks for the other suggestions, but in the end this was all I needed.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You have several solutions, you can create a contextual filter based on `type` and embed your view with this code `views_embed_view('yourview','page',$field['type'])` in this way a special view based on this filter will be loaded.

the second solution is to create separate pages for different types, for example page_type1, page_type2 and ... , then in this code `views_embed_view` use the relevant `page` based on the `type`.

I've used both methods and it works

Answer (score 0):

Using the code below you can add class to the fields as per the value of field_type

```
$form['field_type']['#attributes']['class'] = array(
 drupal_html_class($form['field_type']['und'][0]['value']),
);
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe the [Semantic Views](https://drupal.org/project/semanticviews) module supports tokenized classes. Here is the module description:

> This Views plugin makes unformatted styles, field row styles and other
>   output more readily configurable without needing to override template
>   files. Instead of overriding row style templates for views where you
>   want to specify different HTML elements (tags) and class attributes,
>   you can specify these inside the Views UI and avoid overriding
>   templates for each view.